# Recursive function, return results as array

Tags: java

How can I change this function to have `String[][]` as a return type and return an array of possible combinations instead of just printing out the found combinations?

```
static void combinations2(String[] arr, int len, int startPosition, String[] result){
    if (len == 0){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
        result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
        combinations2(arr, len-1, i+1, result);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
combinations2({ "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" }, 2, 0);
```

should return

```
{ { "Value1", "Value2" }, {"Value1", "Value3"}, {"Value2", "Value3"} }
```

Comment: You don't have a `String[][]` which can be returned from the method.

Comment: First off, you have to change the return type.  Second, what are you trying to stuff into the returned array?

Comment: where are printing the found combination ?

Comment: @Andrew The returned array should contain an array of possible combinations of the original contents of `arr` (as an array).

Comment: I added an example how the method should be invoked / what should be returned in the OP for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
static void combinations2(String[] arr, int len, int startPosition, String[] result, String[][] allResults){
    if (len == 0){
        //Add result to allResults here
        return;
    }
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
        result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
        combinations2(arr, len-1, i+1, result);
    }
}

foo() {
    String[][] allResults = new String[][];
    combinations2(...);
    //allResults now holds all the String[]. 
    //No return statement necessary since arrays, like all Java objects, are passed as references.
}
```

But you're probably better off with `allResults` as an `ArrayList<String[]>`.

Comment: How would I add each result to the allResults array? I think there is something missing in your example.

Comment: *since arrays are passed by reference* - Java is purely **pass-by-value**. I suggest you censor out that statement or may be modify it.

Comment: @R.J: true, I rephrased it. That distinction always gets me :)

Comment: @Zulakis: that's why I suggested using an `ArrayList`. With an array, you're going to have to know how much space you need ahead of time. Save yourself the trouble and use an `ArrayList`. If you absolutely must use an array, you could copy the contents over to a larger array each time the current one runs out of space.

Comment: Using your method with an ArrayList just returns the same combination 3 times. See example of both methods here: http://pastebin.com/wBJ60HY2